# How to style links as buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style links as buttons. There are two problems with my code:

1) The margins don't work, so the buttons overlap.
2) Button width depends on link text. The width value seems to get ignored.

Is there something wrong with my approach or can I make some small changes to make this work?

```
<div class='button1'>
   <a rel="nofollow" href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Option 1</a>
   <br>
   <a rel="nofollow" href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Option 111111</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button1
{

text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;

}

.button1 a
{
width: 20px;
margin: 40px;
padding-top: .6em;
padding-bottom: .6em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #7ca500;
border-radius: 5px;
border: solid #cccccc 3px;
}

.button1 a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #86b200;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to the anchor tags, your margins and width values will work as expected. By default, `<a>` elements are `display: inline;`

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yElua)

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is to use the a DIV to make it look like a button:

**the HTML:**

```
<div class='button1'>
  <a rel="nofollow" href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Option 1</a>
</div>
<div class='button1'>
  <a rel="nofollow" href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Option 2</a>
</div>
```

**the CSS:**

```
.button1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7ca500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid #cccccc 3px;
    padding: .6em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
}

.button1:hover
{
  background-color: #86b200;
}

.button1:active
{
  background-color: red;
}

.button1 a
{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXr7k/)**
I used the `<div class="button1">` 2 times, one for every button.